# Start MySQL server Automatically

Tags: mysql

I am using digital ocean server Ubuntu based facing issue due to MySQL server stop working automatically every time we need to start service of MySQL server. Is their any script for MySQL to start automatically when it's gone down or we received an email message from server regarding same.

Comment: MySQL server should be a service, and by default it should be run during booting up the OS.

Comment: can you provide the mysql version on your question. Since 5.6 and 5.7 have their config in different directories

Comment: This one is for serverfault or linux&unix... I fear it's OT here. :( Anyway, ubuntu uses systemd so it should be `systemctl enable <service>` (see https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd)

Comment: Sorry: didn't get it's about restart after failure... check out https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd#Examples (same page as before, but a specific section) and see what you have configured for mysql

Comment: mysql version is 5.5.4

Comment: i wan t like a cron job when mysql service stop then cron job will automatically start mysql server.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes MySQL stopped working, and I need to login into server many to start the services. I want some solution I don't need to start MySQL server manually, Is there any script I can add on the server if MySQL is stopped working then its automatically start.